# C++ compiling error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"

Tags: c++11, makefile, compilation, compiler-errors, g++4.8

I am using g++ version 4.8.5. I am trying to compile my project using it. It compiles without a problem, when compiling directly from the terminal. But, when using a make file, it gives me following error, even though I am using the same option.

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

**Edit:**
as requested, here's my `makefile` line:

```
main: main.cc
    @g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o run
```

Comment: Can you post the Makefile somewhere?

Comment: @solti Ah, I didn't know about that. Why do I need to have two dashes ?

Comment: You don't, `-std=c++11` is a correct compiler switch for C++11

Comment: Hmm, have you tried specifying g++'s absolute path? Something like this: @/usr/bin/g++-4.8 -std=c++11 main.cpp -o run

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge krzaq seems to be correct .. when I tried your make file in computer it works .. all it did was `all: @g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o run` I also tried with `--std=c++11` and it works too

Comment: @MartinJungblutSchreiner Thanks buddy. It worked. Problem was the path. When using absolute path, it compiled correctly. Thanks again. Can you put it as an answer ? I can accept that then.

Comment: @solti Yes. Both `-` and `--` seems to be working.

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge great ... I also learned in the process :)

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge Sure, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using g++'s absolute path:

```
main: main.cc
    @/usr/bin/g++-4.8 -std=c++11 main.cpp -o run
```